# Unable to appendchild text to element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
myText = document.getElementById("myText")
texts = myText.getElementsByTagName("text");

let div = document.createElement("div");

console.log("Texts length: " + texts.length);
for (let j = 1; j < texts.length; j++) {
  div.appendChild(texts[j]);
}

div.style.display = "none";
myText.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id ="myText">
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="193.25" y="-178.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">Running</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-152.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &lt;onentry &gt; </text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-137.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &#160;&lt;log expr=&#39; &#39;Running!&#39;&#39; &#160;&gt;</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-106.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &#160;&lt;/log&gt;</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-75.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">&lt;/onentry&gt;</text>
  
  </div>
```

When the function ends, I have the following result.

```html
<div id="myText">
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="193.25" y="-178.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">Running</text>
  
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-137.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &nbsp;&lt;log expr=' 'Running!'' &nbsp;&gt;</text>
  
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-75.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">&lt;/onentry&gt;</text>
  
  <div style="display: none;">
<text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-152.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &lt;onentry &gt; </text><text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-106.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &nbsp;&lt;/log&gt;</text></div>
</div>
```

Two out of the four text elements were not properly inserted into the new div. I am not sure why, can anyone help?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a live HTMLCollection so as you move elements to the new `<div>` you alter the length of the queried collection. You're also starting your loop at `1` which skips the first element because array-likes are zero indexed in javascript.

Comment: Also, Array indexes start from 0 in javascript, so your loop should be `let j = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Basically append child also removes the element from its previous position.

Thereby changing length and the element at index j, a better approach would be to store length and then get first element since the list becomes shorter

```html
        length = texts.length;
        for(let j = 1; j < length; j++){
            div.appendChild(texts[1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pilchard's answer is a direct response to your question. This, however, is a method of sidestepping the issue by using querySelectorAll which returns a static NodeList instead of a live HTMLCollection.

When you simplify a bit and use a `forEach` loop, you eliminate the need for a `for` loop and cuts the code down a bit. I am populating a new div with the data for demonstration

```js
myText = document.getElementById("newText")
texts = document.querySelectorAll("text");
let div = document.createElement("div");
texts.forEach(el => div.appendChild(el));
document.getElementById("myText").style.display = "none";
myText.appendChild(div);
```

```css
text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myText">
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="193.25" y="-178.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">Running</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-152.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &lt;onentry &gt; </text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-137.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &#160;&lt;log expr=&#39; &#39;Running!&#39;&#39; &#160;&gt;</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-106.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &#160;&lt;/log&gt;</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-75.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">&lt;/onentry&gt;</text>

</div>

<div id="newText">

</div>
```

Comment: You've actually avoided the OPs problem by using `querySelectorAll` which returns a static `NodeList` instead of a live `HTMLCollection`. It's not the `forEach` that is doing this, but the NodeList that forEach is a method of. (HTMLCollection doesn't implement a forEach() method).

Comment: Thanks @pilchard - I adjusted my answer to reflect that information

Comment: You should also indicate that it is actually using [`NodeList#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) rather than the `Array#` method since NodeList doesn't implement all the Array methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things going wrong in your code.

First of all, you need to declare your variables.

```js
const myText = ...
const texts = ...
```

Next, `getElementsByTagName()` returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which mutates to match changes to the DOM. This means that as you move elements to the new `<div>` you alter the length of the queried collection causing your loop to end before it's had a chance to iterate the entire collection.

If you move your `console.log()` inside the loop you'll see the length is one shorter on each iteration.

```js
const myText = document.getElementById("myText");
const texts = myText.getElementsByTagName("text");

const div = document.createElement("div");
for (let j = 1; j < texts.length; j++) {
  console.log(`Texts length: ${texts.length}, j: ${j}`);
  div.appendChild(texts[j]);
}

console.log(`Texts length: ${texts.length}`);
```

```html
<div id ="myText">  <text text-anchor="middle" x="193.25" y="-178.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">Running</text>  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-152.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &lt;onentry &gt; </text>  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-137.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &#160;&lt;log expr=&#39; &#39;Running!&#39;&#39; &#160;&gt;</text>  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-106.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &#160;&lt;/log&gt;</text>  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-75.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">&lt;/onentry&gt;</text></div>
```

You can avoid this by converting the returned HTMLCollection to an array, for example with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
const texts = [...myText.getElementsByTagName("text")];
```

Lastly, you're starting your loop at `1` which skips the first element because arrays (and array-likes like HTMLCollections) are [zero indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#accessing_array_elements) in javascript.

Working final snippet

```js
const myText = document.getElementById("myText");
const texts = [...myText.getElementsByTagName("text")];

const div = document.createElement("div");
for (let j = 0; j < texts.length; j++) {
  div.appendChild(texts[j]);
}

div.className='new';
myText.appendChild(div);
```

```css
.new {
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div id ="myText">
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="193.25" y="-178.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">Running</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-152.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &lt;onentry &gt; </text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-137.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &#160;&lt;log expr=&#39; &#39;Running!&#39;&#39; &#160;&gt;</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-106.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00"> &#160;&lt;/log&gt;</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="75.5" y="-75.8" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">&lt;/onentry&gt;</text>
</div>
```

All that being said, I'm not sure what you're doing with your `<text>` elements but it's outside the scope of you question so I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Perfect the issue was I did not realize the length got shorter on each iteration, for some reason I thought it had to do with the weird content of the text tag.

So I stored the length before the loop and just iterated that many times using the first element each time.

I deliberately started the loop at 1 because I did not want to get the first element